# Trouble Calling AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video

I am having issues getting my handler called, I've added a println "called handler" to see if my trailing closure gets called but it never does.  The code compiles fine and runs.  This is also part of a XCTest case.  What is going on?

```
    println("going to genenerate images... count: \(array.count)")
    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes(array) { (time: CMTime, image: CGImage!, cmtTime: CMTime, result:
        AVAssetImageGeneratorResult, error: NSError!) in

        println("called handler")
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorResult.Succeeded) {
            if var value = UIImage(CGImage: image) {
                flipBookImagesArray.append(value)
            }

        }
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorResult.Failed) {
            println("Failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription) , \(error.code)")
        }
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorResult.Cancelled) {
            println("Cancelled")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `XCTestExpectation` to wrap asynchronous processes in a unit test:

```
func testAssetImageGenerator() {

    // configure `array`, `generator`, etc. here

    // now, create expectation

    let expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes")

    // have a counter to keep track of how often `generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes` will be called

    var imageCount = array.count

    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes(array) { (time: CMTime, image: CGImage!, cmtTime: CMTime, result:
        AVAssetImageGeneratorResult, error: NSError!) in

        println("called handler")
        if (result == .Succeeded) {
            // do your success stuff in here
        }
        if (result == .Failed) {
            XCTFail("Failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription) , \(error.code)")
        }
        if (result == .Cancelled) {
            XCTFail("Cancelled")
        }

        imageCount--
        if imageCount < 1 {
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
    }

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30, handler: nil)

    XCTAssertEqual(imageCount, 0, "We still have \(imageCount) left")
}
```

This gives your asynchronous process a chance to complete before completing the test.

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into similar issues.
This code was running part of a Unit Test case which Asserted before the Closure gets called.

So basically the function will get called and exits before the closure gets its time to run.